# Determine if a text file without BOM is UTF8 or ASCII

Tags: validation, utf-8, ascii, extended-ascii

Long story short:
+ I'm using ffmpeg to check the artist name of a MP3 file.
+ If the artist has asian characters in its name the output is UTF8.
+ If it just has ASCII characters the output is ASCII.

The output does not use any BOM indication at the beginning.

The problem is if the artist has for example a "ä" in the name it is ASCII, just not US-ASCII so "ä" is not valid UTF8 and is skipped.

How can I tell whether or not the output text file from ffmpeg is UTF8 or not? The application does not have any switches and I just think it's plain dumb not to always go with UTF8. :/

Something like this would be perfect:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/isutf8

If anyone knows of a Windows version?

Thanks a lot in before hand guys!

Comment: *"ASCII, just not US-ASCII"* doesn't make sense.  If `'ä'` is represented as a single byte, it's neither ASCII (because ASCII can only represent 128 characters) nor UTF-8 (because UTF-8 uses 2 bytes to represent `'ä'`).  It might be Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) or one of the Windows code pages such as Windows-1252.  And if a text file has no characters outside the ASCII 128-value range, then it's both ASCII *and* UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

This program/source might help you:

- [Detect Encoding for In- and Outgoing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx)

> Detect the encoding of a text without BOM (Byte Order Mask) and choose the best Encoding ...

Answer (score 0):

You say, *"ä" is not valid UTF-8* ... This is not correct...
It seems you don't have a clear understanding of what UTF-8 is.  UTF-8 is a system of *how* to encode *Unicode Codepoints*.  The issue of validity is notin the character itself, it is a question of how has it been encoded...
There are many systems which can encode *Unicode Codepoints*; UTF-8 is one and UTF16 is another... `"ä"`  is quite legal in the UTF-8 system.. Actually all characters are valid, so long as that character has a Unicode Codepoint.

However, ASCII has only 128 valid values, which equate identically to the first 128 characters in the Unicode Codepoint system.  Unicode itself is nothing more that a big look-up table. What does the work is teh encoding system; eg. UTF-8.

Because the 128 ASCII characters are identical to the first 128 Unicode characters, and because UTF-8 can represent these 128 values is a single byte, just as ASCII does, this means that the data in an ASCII file **is** identical to a file with the same date but which you call a UTF-8 file. Simply put: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8... they are indistinguishable for data in the ASCII range (ie, 128 characters).

You can check a file for 7-bit ASCII compliance..

```
# If nothing is output to stdout, the file is 7-bit ASCII compliant 
# Output lines containing ERROR chars -- to stdout

  perl -l -ne '/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/ or print' "$1"
```

---

Here is a similar check for UTF-8 compliance..

```
perl -l -ne '/
   ^( ([\x00-\x7F])              # 1-byte pattern
     |([\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF])   # 2-byte pattern
     |((([\xE0][\xA0-\xBF])|([\xED][\x80-\x9F])|([\xE1-\xEC\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]))([\x80-\xBF])) # 3-byte pattern
     |((([\xF0][\x90-\xBF])|([\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])|([\xF4][\x80-\x8F]))([\x80-\xBF]{2}))       # 4-byte pattern
    )*$ /x or print' "$1"
```